# dictionary value changes without performing any update

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Why are the values getting updated for every key?

```
d = {0: [0], 1: [0, 1]}
for i in range(2, 4):
    d[i] = d[i - 1]
    d[i].append(i)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: [0], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

I want it like this in the output:

```
{0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and the possible solutions?
It would be great if you could attach the related Python documentation!

Comment: `d = {i:list(range(i+1)) for i in range(3)}` ?

Comment: Thank you. I can do that but the problem was why the values are getting updated for every key

Comment: Lists are references. You set all your dictionary keys to the same reference and slowly add to this reference. All lists above 0 are _the same list_ - not copys. because you re-added the same  reference over and over.

Comment: `for i in d: print(i, d[i], id(d[i]) )` will show you the same id for all the values you copied

Comment: Lists are *objects*; the values in the dictionary are references to those lists.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Assigning a list will copy the elements by reference. Copy the values of the list using `.copy()` method.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
> bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
> mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
> can change one copy without changing the other.

```
d = {0: [0], 1: [0, 1]}
for i in range(2, 4):
    d[i] = d[i - 1].copy()
    d[i].append(i)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

**Explanation:**

When we use `d[i] = d[i-1]` in `d[i]` stores the reference of the list stored in `d[i-1]`. Then when we are updating `d[i]` with the `d[i].append(i)` it updates the list of `d[i-1]` index too.

Comment: Thank you so much! but I wish to know what's wrong in my code "d[i] = d[i-1]" why it's updating everywhere ??

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal it's because you're appending values to the same reference inside the loop. You can python's `id(obj)` (gives hash-value of obj) to check the reference of an object.